# use a portable software as a global app

Tags: fedora, gnome

I'm with Fedora 38 (previously Mint). I have pdfsam-visual subscription, but they have no rpm/flathub option, only portable. The poratble comes as zip, inside there's a .sh that open the application.o Only way that I know to open the app then, is to execute the .sh from the terminal. I wish to be able to open this app like every other app, just press super and write the name.
How can this be achieved?
Thanks, Gal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.desktop` file for your application and place it in `~/.local/share/applications`. The `.desktop` file, also known as [Desktop Entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/), is a simple ini file that describes how to start a particular program.

Here is an example desktop entry

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Name=pdfsam-visual
Exec=/path/to/the/app/launch.sh
Type=Application
# the working directory to run the program in.
Path=/home/myuser
Icon=/path/to/icon.svg
Terminal=false
```

More keys can be found in the [Documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html).